# display confirmation box on delete action link click event using partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is my **Main view** page on which i am displaying kendo grid to show **list of category**:

```
     <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#categories-grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "json",
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("categoriesList", "Admin"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: '',
                                }
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: "Data",
                                total: "Total",
                                errors: "Errors"
                            },
                            error: function (e) {
                                display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                this.cancelChanges();
                            },
                            pageSize: 9,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: [10, 20, 30]
                        },
                        editable: {
                            confirmation: false,
                            mode: "inline"
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "CategoryId",
                                title: "Action",
                                width: 10,
                                template: '<a title="Edit" href="/Admin/ViewCategoryDetails?categoryId=#=CategoryId#&categoryName=#=CategoryName#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>'
                            },
                            {
                                field: "CategoryName",
                                title: "CategoryName",
                                width: 10
                            },
                            {
                                field: "CategoryId",
                                title: "Action",
                                width: 10,
                                //template: '<a class="delete" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>'
                                template: '<a href="/Admin/DeleteParentCategory"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>'

                            }]
                });

                });

        </script>

@Html.Partial("DeleteParentCategory")
```

this script display list of all categories in kendo grid.in kendo grid i am having one edit button and delete button.

on delete button i want to ask for confirmation to user to delete categories.

below is my delete link :

```
 template: '<a href="/Admin/DeleteParentCategory"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>'
```

now i want to call these **partial view on above delete action link**:

this is my **Admin controller** action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult DeleteParentCategory()
        {
            return PartialView("DeleteParentCategory");
        }
```

in this partial view i am just having my modal pop up html code css and js references.

now what is happening is when my **main view** is displayed then this modal pop up message is also displayed and when **i click on delete action link** then that **pop up opens** but my **main view doesnt display**.my main view that is **grid is lost on delete action link.**

can anybody tell me how to display only partial view on click of delete action link with my grid display???

i am very much new in mvc.so guys can u please help me???????????

this is my Delete partial view(Modal Pop up Box Design):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src=" http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
@*<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">*@

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please provide contents of DeleteParentCategory partial view?

Answer (score 0):

your main view goes like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src=" http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#categories-grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("categoriesList", "Admin"))",
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: '',
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: "Data",
                            total: "Total",
                            errors: "Errors"
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                            this.cancelChanges();
                        },
                        pageSize: 9,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverSorting: true
                    },
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: [10, 20, 30]
                    },
                    editable: {
                        confirmation: false,
                        mode: "inline"
                    },
                    scrollable: false,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "CategoryId",
                            title: "Action",
                            width: 10,
                            template: '<a title="Edit" href="/Admin/ViewCategoryDetails?categoryId=#=CategoryId#&categoryName=#=CategoryName#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>'
                        },
                        {
                            field: "CategoryName",
                            title: "CategoryName",
                            width: 10
                        },
                        {
                            field: "CategoryId",
                            title: "Action",
                            width: 10,
                            template: '<a class="delete" onClick="myFunction(); return false;"  href=""><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>'

                        }]
                  });

            });

        function myFunction() {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 190,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Delete all items": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
@Html.Partial("DeleteParentCategory")
```

and DeleteParentCategory partial view goes like this

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?" style="display:none">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;">
</span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: not working.my main view page doesnt display and pop up is also not opening.instead it display those message that is in p tag on new page

Comment: but then how do i fire post event and how do i get those values(that is ok and cancel value of dialog box)

Comment: I am not sure about the Kendo way of doing the inline delete of the grid row..
may be you can make an ajax call for delete and update the grid after success of ajax call..

Comment: can u show the code of ajax  through how i can call post method along with passing value of modal ok and cancle value.i have very little bit idea related with ajax.so can u please help me with ajax?

Comment: to me it looks like the scope of the original post ends here, and for other ajax related question you can post separate question or do a little google..